# Incompatible Types Java

Tags: java, swing

this is my first question. 
And this problem has been eating me inside. So basically everytime i compile my program i get an error and it's as follows:

```
**Paint.java:40: error: incompatible types: java.awt.Point cannot be converted to
Point
                        pt = me.getPoint();
                                        ^
Paint.java:45: error: incompatible types: java.awt.Point cannot be converted to
Point
                        pt = me.getPoint();
                                        ^
2 errors**
```

Here's my Code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Paint extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener{


    /*public class Point {
        public int x, y; // Possible

        public int getX(){ return x;}
        public int getY(){ return y;}

    }*/

    private Point pt = new Point();
    private Graphics g;

    public Paint(){
        super("Painter");
        add(new Label("Drag mouse to draw"),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.fillOval((int) pt.getX(), (int)pt.getY(), 5,5);
    }


    @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me){
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)getGraphics();
            g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawLine(pt.x,pt.y, me.getX(), me.getY());
            pt = me.getPoint();
        }

    @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me){
            pt = me.getPoint();
        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Paint();
    }

}
```

This program is supposed to end up as a Simple Paint Program. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you clean after you commented out your own `Point` class?

Comment: When in doubt, remove all imports and recreate them one after another, otherwise you might end with loads of useless imports.

Comment: Also, while the problem in this case is a stale `Point.class` file, wildcard imports are notorious for this sort of problem. Use an IDE, and it will manage them individually for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your own point class completely, then save, then recompile and run.

Answer (score 0):

```
pt = me.getPoint();
```

You're trying to get java.awt.Point into your variable pt, which has different type Point. Why do you create your own class Point?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question compiles without any errors. The error is reproducible only when the `Point` class is uncommented after which you're trying to convert the java.awt.Point returned from the `MouseEvent` reference `me` into your custom `Paint.Point` type.

Here are a couple of options for you:

1. Remove your custom `Point` inner class and continue using `java.awt.Point`.
2. If you really need the custom `Point` class, write a helper method that converts `java.awt.Point` to `Paint.Point` like below:

`public Point convertPoint(java.awt.Point p) {
        Point myP = new Point();
        myP.x = p.x;
        myP.y = p.y;
        return myP;
    }`